# How to tile single elements in recylerview when adding one at a time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-cardview

So this is probably a simple answer that I don't know the answer to.

I have an add button above a recylerview. When add button is pressed it adds 1 Editview to the recyclerview and then gets focus on the editview so info can be added.

This works great and as expected, however when you click on add button againm it does the same thing with the exception that it adds it below the prior one.  What I want is the EditView to be side by side with no more than 2 in a row.

My current xml file is a constraintview inside of a cardview.  Maybe it should be a gridview instead of a card view and then do a mod to see how many items there are and redo the layout with each press of the add button?

Is that the solution or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "side by side"? Side by side in the same item view or in the new item? And a suggestion, do not start with ConstraintLayout, first get confortable with Relative/Linear/Frame..Layout.

Comment: Side by side means 2 items in one row.  And I did not start with a constraint layout.  I started with LinearLayout and then a constraint layout.  However I did solve the issue with recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solved the issue.  I removed cardview from xml and replaced it with a LinearLayout and within LinearLayout used a constraintLayout.

Then in MainActivity used the following to create the gridlayout.  And to get 2 items side by side set the variable numberOfColumns to 2.
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));